# PI4 - no boot from usb3 samsung t5

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, bootloader, usb3, pi4-eeprom

The steps I have done is:

1. Update/upgrade to the latest Raspberry Pi OS (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade-full`)
2. Update the eeprom firmware (`rpi-eeprom-update`)
3. Clone the SD card using /accessories/SD card copier (to the Samsung t5)
4. Check to see if Samsung is working and shows system files
5. Shut down and remove SD card
6. Power on and screen just shows a looping attempt to boot and fails with ERROR 44

Replacing the SD card just boots from that as normal.

What have I done wrong or missed out?

additional info:

```
vcgencmd bootloader_config
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
DHCP_TIMEOUT=45000
DHCP_REQ_TIMEOUT=4000
TFTP_FILE_TIMEOUT=30000
ENABLE_SELF_UPDATE=1
DISABLE_HDMI=0
BOOT_ORDER=0xf41
```

vgencmd bootloader_version

```
Sep 3 2020 13:11:43
version c305221a6d7e532693cc7ff57fddfc8649def167 (release)
timestamp 1599135103
```

Comment: In 'sudo raspi-config' have you set Boot Options, Boot Mode, USB ?

Comment: What is a "Samsung t5"?

Comment: Samsung T5 is a usb3 SSD

Comment: yes Boot Mode is USB

Comment: What is the output of `vcgencmd bootloader_version` and `vcgencmd bootloader_config` (please add to question, don't post results in comment)

Comment: added additional info to question

Comment: @ikarus Before you add any more info, please look at the output. Use the formatting features of StackExchange editor otherwise it looks like a mess.

Comment: @ikarus I have the same issue. When booting off the samsung t5 raspbian seems to boot fine, but just at the last moment it reboots.  Have you found any cause yet?

Answer (score 1):

I solved (worked around) this problem by attaching the Samsung T5 drive to one of the USB2 ports.

I'm assuming this is a kernel problem and will try the faster USB3 port again on later updates.

Comment: Just follow this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=285806